# A 3 x 3 orthogonal matrix with determinant 1 is a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This has been confusing for a while, so I'll provide my argument in the hope that is it correct.

Suppose $ Q $ is an orthogonal matrix ($ Q^{T} Q  = I $).
It is known that orthogonal matrices preserve the dot product, as $ (Q\mathbf{x}) \cdot (Q\mathbf{y}) = (Q\mathbf{x})^{T} (Q \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{x}^{T} Q^{T} Q \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x}^{T} \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} $ ).

Thus mapping from one orthonormal basis $$  [ \mathbf{e}_{1},\mathbf{e}_{2},\mathbf{e}_{3}] $$ with $ \mathbf{e}_{i} \cdot \mathbf{e}_{j} = \delta_{ij} $ gives another $$ [R \mathbf{e}_{1}, R \mathbf{e}_{2}, R \mathbf{e}_{3}] $$ with $ R\mathbf{e}_{i} \cdot R \mathbf{e}_{j} = \delta_{ij} $, as dot product is preserved.

Morever, this means the lengths of all the vectors and the angles between them are preserved.

Alright, nearly there. So why does $ | Q | = 1 $ mean it must be a rotation?
Suppose $ \mathbf{e}_{1},\mathbf{e}_{2},\mathbf{e}_{3} $ form a right-handed set, ie. they are orientated such that

$$ \mathbf{e}_{1} \cdot (\mathbf{e}_{2} \times \mathbf{e}_{3}) = 1 $$

(We know this is one as being orthonormal, they are unit vectors after all)

Knowing the  [relation between the determinant and the scalar triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) for a 3 x 3 matrix, , if $ | R | = 1 $ it follows that

$$ R \mathbf{e}_{1} \cdot ( R \mathbf{e}_{2} \times  R \mathbf{e}_{3} ) = 1 $$

So it is clear that these vectors are orientated in the same way, hence this transformation must be a rotation. (A similar argument can show $|R| = -1$ gives a reflection).

---

Does that all make sense? Have I missed anything?
I'm interested in seeing a nicer argument if people have got one.
Also, it's tricky to see how this generalises to $n$ dimensions; shedding some light there would be appreciated.

### EDIT

I have looked at this question, [A proof that an orthogonal matrix with a determinant 1 is a rotation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385152/a-proof-that-an-orthogonal-matrix-with-a-determinant-1-is-a-rotation-matrix) but as you can see the argument is pretty bare... so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A proof that an orthogonal matrix with a determinant 1 is a rotation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385152/a-proof-that-an-orthogonal-matrix-with-a-determinant-1-is-a-rotation-matrix)

Comment: What is your definition of “rotation?” What distinguishes it from other linear transformations?

Comment: @amd a rotation fixes only one point (namely, the origin) whereas reflections leave an entire plane fixed (in 3 dimensions)

Comment: There is no 3D rotation that fixes only a single point.

Comment: sorry, *at least one point. sure, that corresponds to a whole axis in 3d

Answer (score 7):

A (real) $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix $Q$ with determinant $1$ has a characteristic polynomial $P(\lambda) = \det(Q - \lambda I)$ that is a cubic with real coefficients.  The coefficient of $\lambda^3$ is $-1$, while the constant coefficient is $\det(Q) = 1$, therefore there must be a positive eigenvalue, and (because $Q$ preserves lengths) this positive eigenvalue can only be $1$.  Thus there is some nonzero vector $w$ that $Q$ leaves fixed.  Since $Q$ preserves the dot product, it maps the plane $V$ orthogonal to $w$ to itself.  The restriction of $Q$ to $V$ corresponds to $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$.
From analysis of $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$, we find that $Q$ acts as a rotation on $V$.  Thus $Q$ is a rotation of $3$-dimensional space around an axis in the direction of $w$.

Comment: Interesting approach, would this generalize easily to higher dimensions?